# How to Store Json Response Of Registration API ? and Getting error of "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format."

Tags: ios, swift, post, alamofire, codable

Hello I'm trying to store my json Response to My Model Class, But I'm getting an error "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format." My Api is working Perfectly fine, only issue is Not storing my data into Data Model Class.

**Here's My Details**

**My Json Response**

```
{
"flag": "1",
"message": "Data inserted.",
"customerId": "60",
"firstName": "fatehlal",
"lastName": "pra",
"animalName": "cat",
"isAround": "1",
"comapnyId": "2",
"company_logo": "http://192.168.1.228/public/img/logosign.png",
"company_name": "Admin",
"mobileNumber": "2345678901"
}
```

**My Register Model**

```
import Foundation

struct RegisterModel : Codable {
let flag : String?
let message : String?
let customerId : String?
let firstName : String?
let lastName : String?
let animalName : String?
let isAround : String?
let comapnyId : String?
let company_logo : String?
let company_name : String?
let mobileNumber : String?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

    case flag = "flag"
    case message = "message"
    case customerId = "customerId"
    case firstName = "firstName"
    case lastName = "lastName"
    case animalName = "animalName"
    case isAround = "isAround"
    case comapnyId = "comapnyId"
    case company_logo = "company_logo"
    case company_name = "company_name"
    case mobileNumber = "mobileNumber"
}

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    flag = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .flag)
    message = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .message)
    customerId = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .customerId)
    firstName = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .firstName)
    lastName = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .lastName)
    animalName = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .animalName)
    isAround = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .isAround)
    comapnyId = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .comapnyId)
    company_logo = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .company_logo)
    company_name = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .company_name)
    mobileNumber = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .mobileNumber)
}

}
```

**My Alamofire Method**

```
  var registerDetail : RegisterModel?
AF.request("http://192.168.1.228/public/api/register", method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).response { response in
             switch response.result {
             case .success(let data) :
                 do {
                        print("SuccessFully Registerd")
                         debugPrint(response.response!)
                         let dataResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(RegisterModel.self, from: data!)
                         self.registerDetail = dataResponse
                 } catch let error {
                     debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
                 }
             case .failure(let error):
                 print(error)

             }

         }
```

Comment: could you try adding `print(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8))` just before `print("SuccessFully Registerd")`
 and tell us what it prints. Note; that you are using "http" Apple does not like that, it wants "https".
 So my guess is you are getting an error message, and that is not decodable to your `RegisterModel`.

Comment: Yes... It is printing actual response.

Comment: what is it printing?

Comment: {"flag":"1","message":"Data inserted.","customerId":"85","firstName":"Fateh","lastName":"Fateh","animalName":"Hg ggg c","isAround":1,"comapnyId":"1","company_logo":"http:\/\/192.168.1.228\/public\/img\/comapny\/1\/logo-.png","company_name":"Super Admin","mobileNumber":"gggfgggff"}

Comment: from that you can see `isAround` is not a String, like in your model.

Comment: I got It... Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

given your data, use: `let isAround : Int?`